# How do I test if two <img> are touching each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I'm trying to create this mini-game where you fight each other. I used two `<img>`s as the characters and I got the movement down on both of the `<img>`s but, I want to make it so when the `<img>`s are touching you have a option to punch them.

All I'm asking is how to test if they are touching. I'm pretty sure I can handle everything else and if not I can look whatever up. I've tried looking it up hundreds of times, but none of them really talking about `<img>`s only like divs. If they do talk about `<img>`s it's very confusing.

Comment: Why can't you apply what "they" say about `<div>` elements to `<img>` elements?

Answer (score 0):

One way to check if two `<img>` elements are touching or overlapping with each other is to utilize the [`$.position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/), [`$.height()`](http://api.jquery.com/height/) and [`$.width()`](http://api.jquery.com/width/) functions to retrieve the top-left position, height and width of each element, respectively.

Using these functions, you can then calculate the four coordinates, top-left, top-right, bottom-left and bottom-right, of your image element. Each coordinate should have an x-coordinate and a y-coordinate. Then you will also have to implement your `overlap` algorithm to check the image elements' coordinates to see if they are touching or overlapping with each other.

You can take a look at this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ivan_sim/pgogvbc3/).

- The `coordinates` function calculates the four coordinates of an element.
- The **incomplete** `overlap` function checks the coordinates of the two element.
- You can slide the second image horizontally by changing the value of the `right` css property.

Like I said, the `overlap` function is **incomplete**; it only checks if the top x-coordinates of both elements touch/overlaps. (Not gonna do the whole thing for you :-))

There may be other simpler ways to do this, but this works for a game that I built.

Comment: Note: You can also use [getBoundingClientRect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/442404/retrieve-the-position-x-y-of-an-html-element) method.